# Recommendations on templates/libraries for a reporting web porting with kendo ui asp.net mvc

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am looking into building a responsive modern web portal, primarily for reporting purposes like data, stats and few charts. Especially for charts I plan to use Kendo UI controls. Apart from that are there recommendations on what templates to use with ASP.NET MVC such as bootstrap or something else that gives a good look and feel to the web UI? I am new to javascript so something that is quick to pick up, or with good documentation also would work.

Answer (score 0):

The kendo ui controls come with a number of themes that are perfect for this type of exercise (I'm doing something similar to you with a "reporting" portal. I have found that the bootstrap and flat themes are the best to use (flat for graphs looks amazing). If you look at the kendo demo's they will show you the power of the suite especially this one: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bootstrap/ it shows the integration with bootstrap really nicely and is probably something similar to what you may be after.

I am using the kendo controls with the bootstrap theme currently for my project and they seem to fit well together, like you I'm not the best at javascript (although I have learnt loads just using these two libraries) - Thanks Telerik for the MVC helpers!